# How to have a listview with textbox editable in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datagrid

While I'm posting this. I thought, I can use a datagrid.

Is so complex to create a listview editable or is better to use the datagrid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that hard, just add a [`GridViewColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.aspx) with a [`CellTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.celltemplate.aspx) that contains a `TextBox`.

The `DataGridTextColumns` are a bit more simple though as you just need to specify the `Binding` while the `TextBox` is created automatically. You could create a custom class for `GridViews` (`GridViewTextColumn`) which does the same thing though.

Comment: I can imagine I've got to interact the property IsSelected, right?

Comment: I mean, I've gotta use triggers to implement it

Comment: Oh, you mean that the TextBox only appears when the item is selected? In that case triggers would be an option.