# Listview DataTemplate Binding returning an error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to switch over to WPF from Winform and so far it's a pain.

Anyway, I am trying to get this binding thing to work using DataTemplate.

I have a class:

```
public class TranslatorListItem
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string OriginalMessage { get; set; }
    public string TranslatedMessage { get; set; }
    public string Sector { get; set; }
}
```

Items are added like this:

```
TranslatorListItem TLI = new TranslatorListItem();
TranslatorLVI.Items.Add(TLI);
```

My XAML DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
    <Border BorderBrush="#FFA4D5E5" BorderThickness="1,1,0,0" Margin="6">
        <StackPanel Margin="6,2,6,2">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="#00000000" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

This is how I'm trying to bind the data but it's returning this error: "Two-way binding requires Path or XPath."

```
    <ListView Margin="23,224,27,54" Name="TranslatorLVI" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyItemContainerStyle}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Item" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Item}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Original Message" Width="300" CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Translated Message" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=TranslatedMessage}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Sector" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Sector}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

I need TranslatedMessage binding to be editable. So that field wont be Read-Only. 
I heard I may need to set Two-way binding, but I am not sure how to do so.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: are you getting your listview populated?

Comment: MyDataTemplate TextBox Text binding doesn't contain Path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to switch over to WPF from Winform and so far it's a pain.

No, it's not. WPF is the best UI Framework in the history of mankind. winforms (or anything else) can't even be compared with it.

Your problem is you're trying to use a winforms approach in WPF and you fail.
WPF does not support developers with a winforms mentality.

All the horrible code behind hacks you're used to from winforms are completely unneeded in WPF.

Please read [Rachel's Excellent Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15684569/643085) (and linked blog posts) about the mindshift needed when upgrading from winforms to WPF.

---

As mentioned in @JasRaj's answer, you're missing a `DisplayMemberBinding` in this case. I tested your code and added that, like this:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Original Message" 
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding OriginalMessage}"  
                Width="300"/>
```

And it worked perfectly.

---

After a second read to your question I realized you wanted to make one of these columns editable.

First of all I will say that while what you want *can* be achieved with a `ListView`, using a `DataGrid` [is easier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9318870/643085).

You need to remove the `DisplayMemberBinding`s from the `ListView` in order to use a `CellTemplate`, and therefore you need to modify the template slightly:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
        <Border BorderBrush="#FFA4D5E5" BorderThickness="1,1,0,0" Margin="6">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding TranslatedMessage}" 
                     TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                     BorderThickness="0" 
                     BorderBrush="#00000000" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I have placed a `ListView` and a `DataGrid` side by side so you can compare them:

[image]

Here is the XAML:

```
<UniformGrid Columns="2">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Item" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Item}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Original Message" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding OriginalMessage}"  Width="300"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Translated Message" CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Sector"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item" Binding="{Binding Path=Item}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Original Message" Binding="{Binding OriginalMessage}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="300"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Translated Message" Binding="{Binding TranslatedMessage}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sector" Binding="{Binding Sector}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</UniformGrid>
```

- Notice how the ListView requires `DataTemplates` in order to support edition, and is read-only by default, while the `DataGrid` is editable by default, does not need any special templats and requires that you add the `IsReadOnly="True"` to columns that are intended to be read-only.
- Also, I noticed you're adding items manually to the `ListView` using procedural code. This is not desired in WPF. You must use an `ObservableCollection<>` and manipulate that collection, and let the WPF Binding engine update the UI for you.
- It is recommended and desired that you [Separate logic/data from UI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14382137/643085) in WPF.
- If you need further clarification please let me know.
- WPF Rocks.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the big help and blogs about WPF. I'll be sure to read them soon. I would like to use the cell template on both OriginalMessage and TranslatedMessage. However, when I bind them like this:                     
<TextBox Text="{Binding OriginalMessage}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding TranslatedMessage}" />
The value is invalid because it adds Translated to Original and displays both. How would I fix this problem? Thank you!

Comment: @JonJon2244 you need 2 separate `DataTemplate`s. One for each column.

Comment: Yea, that's the way I'm doing it now but I thought there would be a cleaner way :/

Answer (score 1):

Bind the second columns of Gridview with OriginalMessage property.

like :-

DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=OriginalMessage}"

it should work.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion  you dont fully use the datatemplate. you just use it to display one property;
In fact you can use a DataTemplate to display all data in  thie class （TranslatorListItem）;
such as this

```
     <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
            <Border BorderBrush="#FFA4D5E5" BorderThickness="1,1,0,0" Margin="6">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Item}" 
                         TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                         BorderThickness="0" 
                         BorderBrush="#00000000" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding TranslatedMessage}" 
                             TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                             BorderThickness="0" 
                             BorderBrush="#00000000" />
                  （ ..... follow up)
                  </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
So your ListView  can design like this:
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}"> 
    </ListView>
```